# app in Docker container can't locate csv file in root directory?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

My app inside a container is trying to open a csv file, `os.Open("file.csv")` , however it cannot locate the csv file inside root directory of my project, it's not being copied over...

My project set up, here is the root of my project

```
Dockerfile
health-check/  # This is where the code for my app is, inside this folder
file.csv # File that app needs to open is in the root directory.
```

Here is my Dockerfile

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

##
## Build
##
FROM golang:1.18-buster AS build

WORKDIR /app

COPY health-check/ .
RUN go mod download

RUN go build -o /health-check-ping

##
## Deploy
##
FROM gcr.io/distroless/base-debian10

WORKDIR /

COPY --from=build /health-check-ping /health-check-ping

EXPOSE 8080

USER nonroot:nonroot

ENTRYPOINT ["/health-check-ping"]
```

How can I fix my dockerfile so have my CSV file copied over so my app can open is

EDIT:

[image]

I have moved the csv file to `health-check/` and replaced the way my app opens the file by doing the following:
`os.Open("/app/health-check/challenge_dataset.csv")`

My container log is throwing back this error: `open /app/health-check/challenge_dataset.csv: no such file or directory`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is you don't copy the csv file to your docker.
when using `FROM` you change the image you are building so your `copy` become not relevant.
you need to have `COPY health-check/ /app` after the last `FROM` (worked when written the line before the EXPOSE).

Comment: I took your advice and moved the file into `health-check` folder, but still same error. I have not changed the code for how my app locates the file by the way. `os.Open("challenge_dataset.csv")`

Comment: if you copied the file to `health-check` your code should search the file there (`/app/health-check/challenge_dataset.csv`)

Comment: I have updated my post to show how I implemented your advice but still the same issue arises. not able to locate the file.

Comment: what happends if you use `COPY health-check/ /app/health-check` instead of `COPY health-check/ .`?

Comment: the build fails because `RUN go mod download` needs to be ran where the contents of `health-check/` are.

Comment: so I recommand you to write: `COPY challenge_dataset.csv /app` and than `os.Open("/app/challenge_dataset.csv")`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246443/discussion-between-aking-and-andres).